# Countdown for few tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few tabs, and on socket event  I want to countdown for all opens tabs. I'm trying to do somethink like this:

```
var calendar = {
        timer: function (counter, id){
            var t = counter;
            var element = $(document).find('.view'+id);
            var parent = element.parent();
            var e = $('<div style="display: inline" id="timer'+id+'"></div>').appendTo(parent);
            var id = setInterval(function() {
                t--;
                if(t < 0) {                   
                    clearInterval(id);
                    e.remove();
                } else {
                    e.text(t);
                } 
            }, 1000);

        }
    }
```

but I have two problems:
1. This code I can execute for only one element. example:

> **div 1** -> and here is counting down.
>   **div 2** -> here isn't

And in div 1 on each tabs, countdown is different, but it starts at the same time.
Coud someone help?

Comment: could you provide a working pen or a fiddle please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3QMzh/111/ hmm  2 divs working, but When I have opened 2 tabs, then countdown is different (start countdown is emit by socket.io

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comment, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome), *inactive tabs have low priority execution and this can affect JavaScript timers*.

Thus, a solution would be to listen to focus and then resync your socket.io timer.

```
window.addEventListener('focus', function () {
    // request socket.io response
})
```